# Bootstrap striped dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What's the best way to achieve "striped" menu items in a Bootstrap dropdown menu? I want alternating menu items to have a slightly different background shading to make dropdown items that span multiple lines more obviously a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pseudo Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). See example

```css
.dropdown-menu > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu > li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #a94442;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Single button -->
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```